Forge install is not installing the dependencies
I used to clone the code from this repo https://github.com/Gearbox-protocol/dev-bots-tutorial and work on that. Here, when calling forge install the dependencies are properly getting installed. However, even when I copy-paste all the files of the repo into a newly created one, the command forge install is not doing anything, not even throwing errors. I tried to do it with git submodule update --init --remote, commands, but still didn't get any results. I think it's somehow related to the fact that this repository and and the modules that I try to install belong to the same profile in the GitHub, but not totally sure if that is the case, as all of the repos are public there. Is there any way I can solve this problem?

If you're copy-pasting all the files and folders of the repo in a new folder, then you just have to execute the following command to initialize the foundry project with the existing files and folders:
forge init --force

All the dependencies folders inside the lib of the original dev-bots-tutorial repo, are not having any content that they're supposed to be having. That's why, the command forge install is not doing anything.
So, what you can do is:

Install the dependencies by seeing the lib folder of the original dev-bots-tutorial by using the exact commit hashes:
forge install 1inch/solidity-utils@8bf9ccb gearbox-protocol/core-v2@e890150 gearbox-protocol/core-v3@ca43d1b gearbox-protocol/integrations-v3@302c635 openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@932fddf --no-commit


Create a folder named as 1inch folder inside lib, and move the solidity-utils folder into it.

Create a folder named as gearbox-protocol inside lib, and move the core-v2, core-v3 and integrations-v3 into it.


Now, if you've created the .env file with the proper environment variables as mentioned in the .env.example file, then the tests would run fine on executing the forge test command.
P.S. I've created a PR by doing these changes, so you can also reference that if you want.

Thank you for the answer, but the thing is that in this case it only installs the forge-std library, not the other ones.

You’re welcome. Can you please tell what exact error are you getting when you’re running forge test?

import {IPriceOracleV3} from "@gearbox-protocol/core-v3/contracts/interfaces/IPriceOracleV3.sol";
Its not even compiling, because its not downloading the dependencies that's the problem, not the code itself, the same code runs normally, when I call forge install in the fork of the original repository

Are you copying each and every file and folder from the repo to your new folder? Make sure that you're not missing anything.

Yes, everything is copied, and it still doesnt work, however it should work just with the contract itself.

Can you push your folder (in which you’ve copied everything) to a new GitHub repo so that I can check on my end?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

https://github.com/Hakob23/dca-order-bot/tree/master This was posted in the discussion yesterday

The answer works, although it requires some manual setup before calling the comment. But thank you so much for your help :)

You're welcome, @HakobArshakyan. Happy coding!

just clone the repo and the run forge test it worked for me. but if the libraries still doesn't get installed for you by calling forge test you can install them individually from the remappings.txt list by running the forge install:
@ds-test/=lib/forge-std/lib/ds-test/src/
@forge-std/=lib/forge-std/src/
@gearbox-protocol/=lib/gearbox-protocol/
@openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
@1inch/=lib/1inch/ 

install command:
forge install --no-commit foundry-rs/forge-std
forge install --no-commit OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts
forge install --no-commit dapphub/ds-test
forge install --no-commit a16z/erc4626-tests.git
forge install --no-commit Gearbox-protocol/core-v2
forge install --no-commit Gearbox-protocol/core-v3
forge install --no-commit Gearbox-protocol/integrations-v3
forge install --no-commit 1inch/solidity-utils

